# Wordpress plugin to know from which platform visitors coming to my website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, analytics

Is there any Wordpress plugin for visitor and click details, from which platform visitor coming to website and no of visitors from each platform?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins, which provide visitor details like time, os, ip, browser etc.

**Here are the best ones:**

1. [Visitors Traffic Real Time Statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visitors-traffic-real-time-statistics/)
2. [WP Statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/)
3. [StatCounter – Free Real Time Visitor Stats](https://wordpress.org/plugins/official-statcounter-plugin-for-wordpress/)

You can also try other wordpress plugins which provide details about [Visitors](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/visitors/).

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/
see this link

- WP Statistics StatCounter
- Free Real Time Visitor Stats